# center fixed div within bootstrap container class for responsive layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd try to use margin percentage to apply the hack but since it's responsive I have no idea how to centering a fixed div in bootstrap container class. I run my experiment here:

http://jsbin.com/oqOsEGa/1

try to uncheck the position:fixed in developer tool, things go within the container, but I want to apply fixed but align in the container class of bootstrap, how?

Comment: That kinda made sense to me but can you tell me exactly what you want. e.g move class "test" center with fixed pos. something like that.

Comment: @Ruddy I want the img to be fixed, to make it sticky, and it must remain in the container class of bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fixed (sticky) container via Bootstrap, take a look at this post. You can use the **[Affix plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)** for bootstrap.

If you're only trying to center the container, try adding the following to the container class:

```
.container {
    height:200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

- [Bootstrap responsive affixed menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542295/bootstrap-responsive-affixed-menu)
- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix